# What steps should I take to resolve the 'Cypress is not responding' error during test execution in Cypress?

Tags: cypress-component-test-runner

getting error Cypress is not responding.
I tried multiple ways like clear cache and reinstall cypress and tried again but no use still getting same thing. can any one help me please.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mywPE.png)

```
> [type here](https://stackoverflow.com)
```

trying to run cypress tests. but cypress is not responding